# Get all groups of AD users with filter - Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get all groups that start with the following string from a user "DIR-*". With the following command I get all the groups of the user.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof
```

[image: command with filled list]

I then tried to filter with this, but that doesn't work because the list remains empty.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | Where-Object {$_.CN -like "DIR-*"}
```

[image: command with empty list]

Unfortunately, I am still a complete beginner when it comes to Powershell, but I need the command promptly.

I thank you for any help.

Comment: You're trying to filter by a property that is no longer available since you're now working with just the *memberof* values. Place your `Where-Object` before your `Select-Object`. I also don't recall if *CN* is a default property returned, otherwise you will have to specify it as well as an argument for your `-Properties` parameter.

Comment: To summarize and complement @Abraham's comment, the `memberof` attribute will be an array of `DistinguishedName` so by simply replacing `$_.CN` for `$_` the filter should properly work: `....dProperty memberof | Where-Object {$_ -like "DIR-*"}`